# How to create responsive Tradingview Lightweight Chart?

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api, lightweight-charts

I am new to Tradingview charting library and I want to create like responsive chart.

The problem is, trading view charting library requires to specify width and height. Here is the code.

```
const chart = LightweightCharts.createChart(e, {
      width: e.offsetWidth,
      height: e.offsetHeight,
      layout: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(17, 17, 39)',
        textColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)',
      },
      grid: {
        vertLines: {
          color: 'rgb(41, 44, 58)',
        },
        horzLines: {
          color: 'rgb(41, 44, 58)',
        },
      },
      crosshair: {
        mode: LightweightCharts.CrosshairMode.Normal,
      },
      priceScale: {
        borderColor: 'rgba(197, 203, 206, 0.8)',
      },
      timeScale: {
        borderColor: 'rgba(197, 203, 206, 0.8)',
      },
    });
```

Comment: Follow this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68178791/7921804

Answer (score 12):

This is the code from timocov's comment, which just work. Put it after `createChart` and `setData`. and rename chartContainer to your chart container HTML element.

```
  // Make Chart Responsive with screen resize
  new ResizeObserver(entries => {
      if (entries.length === 0 || entries[0].target !== chartContainer) { return; }
      const newRect = entries[0].contentRect;
      chart.applyOptions({ height: newRect.height, width: newRect.width });
    }).observe(chartContainer);
```

Answer (score 6):

Lightweight charts has the option for [`autoSize`](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/ChartOptions#autosize).

> Setting this flag to true will make the chart watch the chart container's size and automatically resize the chart to fit its container whenever the size changes. 
>  
>  This feature requires [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) class to be available in the global scope. Note that calling code is responsible for providing a polyfill if required. If the global scope does not have ResizeObserver, a warning will appear and the flag will be ignored.

Comment: this should be the right answer, because not only this works, but also this usese the tools provided by the lybrary instead of using hacks/external code.

Comment: This is only if you have v4.0

Answer (score 1):

You need to detect a resize event on the container element containing the chart, then update the charts dimensions with `chart.applyOptions({ width: newWidth, height: newHeight })`

There are some libraries to detect element resizes, the best non-lib way that I can find is with the `ResizeObserver` API, but it looks like it might not be integrated into all modern browsers yet.  You would set an update callback function using the elements new height/width and use that in the `ResizeObserver`:

```
function resize() {
    chart.applyOptions({ width: $('#chartDiv').width(), height: $('#chartDiv').height() })
}

new ResizeObserver(outputsize).observe($('#chartDiv'))
```

Comment: You don't even need to measure container's height if you're using ResizeObserver:
```
new ResizeObserver(entries => {
 if (entries.length === 0 || entries[0].target !== container) {
  return;
 }

 const newRect = entries[0].contentRect;

 chart.applyOptions({ height: newRect.height, width: newRect.width });
}).observe(container);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty simple solution. Let's assume you create a LightweightChart inside of a `div` container:

```js
    const chartDiv = document.getElementById('chart');
    const chart = LightweightCharts.createChart(chartDiv, {
        // ...
    }
```

Then this will resize the chart on the fly:

```js
    window.onresize = function() {
        chart.applyOptions({ 
            width: chartDiv.offsetWidth, 
            height: chartDiv.offsetHeight 
        });
    }
```